# LLVM physical register mapping

Tags: x86, llvm, cpu-registers, llvm-ir, register-allocation

I have some function in LLVM IR, which has some input arguments. However, I want to keep an argument passed in a register, and I want to compile it only for x86. For instance, I am writing a function containing adding instruction:

```
%sum = add i64 %val1, %val2
```

and no matter which args are in the list, I will guarantee that val1 is in eax, and val2 in ebx physical registers. How can I make a mapping between val1 and eax?

Comment: Maybe you can wrap the operation in function call and instrument that way your IR. Then, you can implement that wrapper in assembly (where you have access to the desired registers) and link it in the final executable as a static archive.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, if we modify GHC calling convention and sort registers in right order. Unfortunately, it is modifying LLVM sources, but it works.